# Save Data in MySQL using AngularJS

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I need to insert and retrieve data using Angularjs with PHP/MySQL:

```
<form>
<label>Customer Name </label><input type="text"/>
<label>Customer Address  </label><input type="text"/>
<label>Customer Image  </label><input type="file"/>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Check the image:

[image]

Comment: So, where's the problem?

Comment: i am still learning angularjs. can you send me reference link to learn it. i checked lot of tutorials. but i could not complete my task using that tuts.

Comment: You don't need Angular for this task, try learning PHP first

Comment: i done it using PHP. now i need to do it using angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is a frontend technology which means it will only work on browser. You cant save data from angularJS to MYSQL, you need to do that in a server application. In your case it is PHP.

To do this first you need to pass the data from client side to server side. Please check the below documentation to see how to make a post request to the server application

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Once you received the data in your php application you can connect to mysql database to insert/udpate the data

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some sites

For basic and simple angular js tutorial
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/

and for the deep and complete documentation
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

And for your above problem, there will a controller that is attached to your view.On the form, form data will be bound to model variable and On click of submit button there will be a method in your controller that will be called with model data. Your controller method will use service method to make an ajax call with provided form data that internally make a connection with MySQL fire query and return back to your controller.